# IntelliJ plugin for CloudFoundry

Tags: intellij-idea, cloud-foundry

Instead of manually pushing the sprint boot service to cloundfoundry, I'm checking to see, if there is any IntelliJ CloudFoundry plugin to deploy a Spring Boot application from IJ IDE to CF space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Cloud Foundry plugin bundled with IntelliJ. You can configure a CF target in `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Clouds`, then [create a Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-cloud-foundry-server.html) to deploy the app to that CF target.